# java compile time error while solving array problem

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, data-structures, compiler-errors

I am new to Java can't understand what i did wrong here

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        int tc = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine().trim());
        while (tc-- > 0) {
            String[] inputLine;
            int n = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine().trim());
            int[] arr = new int[n];
            inputLine = br.readLine().trim().split(" ");
            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
                arr[i] = Integer.parseInt(inputLine[i]);
            }

            int ans = new Solution().print2largest(arr, n);
            System.out.println(ans);
        }
    }
}

// } Driver Code Ends


//User function Template for Java

class Solution {
    int print2largest(int arr[], int n) {
        int large = getLargest(arr,n);
        int res = -1;
        for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
            if(arr[i]!= arr[large]){
                if(res == -1){
                    res = arr[i];
                }
                else if(arr[i]>arr[res]){
                    res = arr[i];
                }
            }
        }
        return res;
    }
}

public static int getLargest(int arr[], int n) {
    int l = 0;
    for(int i=0; i<n; i++){
        if(arr[i]>arr[l]){
            l = i;
        }
    }
    return l;
}
```

I got the following errors

```
prog.java:53: error: class, interface, or enum expected
public static int getLargest(int arr[], int n) {
              ^
prog.java:55: error: class, interface, or enum expected
    for(int i=0; i<n; i++){
    ^
prog.java:55: error: class, interface, or enum expected
    for(int i=0; i<n; i++){
                 ^
prog.java:55: error: class, interface, or enum expected
    for(int i=0; i<n; i++){
                      ^
prog.java:58: error: class, interface, or enum expected
        }
        ^
```

`

This is my input -->
6
12 35 1 10 34 1

I am expecting this result for the given array -->
34

Comment: You having closing braces `}` in wrong places. Make sure to have `}` for methods and the class in the right place

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this method is out of classes.
In Java methods should be part of class.
Keep it in class Solution, It will compile.

```
public static int getLargest(int arr[], int n) {
int l = 0;
  for(int i=0; i<n; i++){
    if(arr[i]>arr[l]){
        l = i;
    }
  }
 return l;
}
```

There is another mistake with your code:

```
if(arr[i]!= arr[large]){
            if(res == -1){
                res = arr[i]; // you are saving element not index
            }
            else if(arr[i]>arr[res]){ // but you are comparing with index, it can give arrayOutOfBound exception. It should be like this arr[i]>res
                res = arr[i]; // you are saving element not index
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Methods must be within a class structure.

*[Declaring Classes (The Java™ Tutorials > Learning the Java Language > Classes and Objects)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classdecl.html)*.

```java
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        int tc = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine().trim());
        while (tc-- > 0) {
            String[] inputLine;
            int n = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine().trim());
            int[] arr = new int[n];
            inputLine = br.readLine().trim().split(" ");
            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
                arr[i] = Integer.parseInt(inputLine[i]);
            }

            int ans = new Solution().print2largest(arr, n);
            System.out.println(ans);
        }
    }
}

// } Driver Code Ends


//User function Template for Java

class Solution {
    int print2largest(int arr[], int n) {
        int large = getLargest(arr,n);
        int res = -1;
        for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
            if(arr[i]!= arr[large]){
                if(res == -1){
                    res = arr[i];
                }
                else if(arr[i]>arr[res]){
                    res = arr[i];
                }
            }
        }
        return res;
    }

    public static int getLargest(int arr[], int n) {
        int l = 0;
        for(int i=0; i<n; i++){
            if(arr[i]>arr[l]){
                l = i;
            }
        }
        return l;
    }
}
```